# Scheme Difficulty Understanding output of my function 'concat lists' output

Tags: scheme, racket, quote

I wrote a function called 'my-append' which which takes two lists L1,L2
and appends each element of L2 to the end of L1. (in other words it concats L1 with L2)

the function seems to be behaving correctly however I seem to be getting a strange output.

```
(my-append '(a b '(1 2 3)) (list '(4 5 6) 7 8 9)) ==>

(list 'a 'b (list 'quote (list 1 2 3)) (list 4 5 6) 7 8 9)
```

I am new to scheme and cannot tell if this is correct or now.
Please note that I am using Advanced student language inside of dr racket.
Here is the code for the function. (it uses two helper functions)

```
;my-append
;takes two lists L1,L2 and returns concat of L2 to L1
;it first checks if either list is empty if so it returns the non empty one
;if both are empty returns empty
;if both are non empty determine which list has smaller length
;calls my-append-helper with first arg as smaller second larger
;append-element
;takes a list L and element x and adds x
; to the end of L
; I am super limited on which operations i can use
; so i must resort to this O(n) algorithm

;my-append-helper
;takes either two non empty lists L1 L2 then
;builds the concatenation of L1 L2
;by stripping of first element of L2
;and adding it to L1

(define (append-element L x)
  (cond ((equal? L '())    
         (list x) )          
        (else           
         (cons (first L)    
                (append-element (rest L) x)))))

(define my-append-helper
  (lambda (L1 L2)
    (cond ( (equal? '() L2)
            L1)
          (else (my-append-helper (append-element L1 (first L2)) (rest L2))))))

(define my-append
  (lambda (L1 L2)
    (cond ( (and (equal? L1 '()) (equal? L2 '()))
            '() )
          ( (equal? L1 '() )
            L2 )
          ( (equal? L2 '() )
            L1)
          ( else
            (my-append-helper L1 L2)))))
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `car` and `cdr` and iterate through the list and add the elements to the new list. What you are doing looks way more complex than need to be.

Comment: I know, it is for a homework assignment so we are using a very restricted set of operations

Comment: Well, if that doesn't work, let me know and I'll try helping you debug your code. Btw racket does have an append function.

Comment: Also I hope you are not doing this under Troeger

Comment: I'm not sure who 'Troeger' is? Is that a professor? Thanks for your algorithm. Unfortunately cdr is one of the band items. With regards to list operations, we can really only use 'first', 'rest' , and 'equals'

Comment: Yes he is a professor. One of the few people I know who refuses to let Racket die. Sorry to hear it was in the ban list, and glad you got your answer!

Comment: `rest` is the same as `cdr` though.

Comment: Where is the function `concat-lists` mentioned in the title? Since it doesnt seem to be important with order (uses tail of longest list) you basically implement `(foldl cons longest-list shortest-list)`. Using `append-element`makes it O(n^2) so if order is important reversing at the end  makes it O(n)

Comment: @WillNess In that case i suppose HarrisNadeem proposed algorithm may have worked. He also used 'car' though and i dont that was on the lsit either. Why however would they have cdr be an alias for rest?

Comment: for historical reasons. they had [`car` and `cdr` first](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/) (there's also a PS/PDF on the net), and much later, aiming for teachability, introduced those two aliases which were deemed to be more self-explanatory. ---- there's an error in HarrisNadeem's code. `cons` must be replaced with an equivalent of your `append-element`, and then we just have your original code back, as present in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the output is correct.

```
> (my-append '(a b '(1 2 3)) (list '(4 5 6) 7 8 9))
(list 'a 'b (list 'quote (list 1 2 3)) (list 4 5 6) 7 8 9)
```

It is printed in the style so that when pasted back at the prompt the result is the same:

```
> (list 'a 'b (list 'quote (list 1 2 3)) (list 4 5 6) 7 8 9)
(list 'a 'b (list 'quote (list 1 2 3)) (list 4 5 6) 7 8 9)  ; compare below     vvvvv
```

How can we be sure it's OK? By doing the same with the two parts:

```
> '(a b '(1 2 3))
(list 'a 'b (list 'quote (list 1 2 3)))
;     --------------------------------
>  (list '(4 5 6) 7 8 9)
                                 (list (list 4 5 6) 7 8 9)  ; aligned vertically  ^^^
;                                      ------------------
```

The *append* just puts the two parts together into one list, turning

```
      (list a b c ... n) (list o p q ... z)
```

into

```
      (list a b c ... n        o p q ... z)
```

or, symbolically ("in *pseudocode*"),

```
           [a b c ... n]      [o p q ... z]   ; is turned into:
           [a b c ... n        o p q ... z]
```

---

About your algorithm. It appends the two lists by repeating the steps

```
           [a b c ... n]      [o p q ... z]  
           [a b c ... n]    o   [p q ... z]   
           [a b c ... n o]        [q ... z]
```

until the second list is exhausted. Repeatedly appending an element at a list's end is well suited for languages with such primitive, like Clojure's `conj`, which is cheap to use. But in Scheme it is algorithmically disadvantageous because the repeated traversal over the first list to append the element to it leads to a *quadratic* behaviour w.r.t. the time complexity (the execution time will grow four-fold for a two-fold increase in the input data's size).

Another way of doing this is

```
           [a b ... m n]      [o p q ... z]  
           [a b ... m]    n   [o p q ... z]   
           [a b ... m]      [n o p q ... z]
```

until the first list is used up:

```
(define my-append-helper
  (lambda (L1 L2)
    (cond ( (equal? '() L1)
            L2)
          (else (my-append-helper (but-last L1) (cons (last L1) L2))))))
                                           ;     ^^^^ !
```

`cons` is cheap in Scheme, so that is good. But repeatedly removing an element from a list's end (with the yet-not-implemented `but-last`) is algorithmically disadvantageous because the repeated traversal over the first list to remove its last element leads to a *quadratic* behaviour w.r.t. the time complexity (the execution time will grow four-fold for a two-fold increase in the input data's size).

We're on the right track with the `cons` though, when we notice that the appending can progress by the steps

```
           [a b ... m n]          [o p q ... z] 
         ( [a]   [b ... m n] )    [o p q ... z]  
           [a] ( [b ... m n]      [o p q ... z] )
                ................................
           [a]   [b ... m n        o p q ... z] 
           [a     b ... m n        o p q ... z]
```

when we set aside the *first* element of the *first* list, append what's left, and then all that is left for us to do is to *`cons`* that first element onto the result!

Answer (score 0):

Does this count?

```
(define (myappend lst1 lst2)
  (cond
    ((null? lst2) lst1)
    (else (myappend (cons lst1 (cons (car lst2) '())) (cdr lst2)))))
```

This is an iterative procedure (rather than recursive).

Note that if

1. List 2 is empty, you can simply return list1.
2. Since your base case requires you to return your list1, just use an invariant based proof where you define list1 to be the invariant.

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll try helping you debug your code.

Comment: `(cons lst1 (cons (car lst2) '()))` isn't *quite* right. :)

Comment: Really? How come? Did I mistype something?

Comment: try it in DrRacket: (define lst1 (list 1 2)) , (define lst2 (list 3 4)) . (cons lst1 (cons (car lst2) '())) is intended to produce (list 1 2 3), right? does it?